# Zend Framework 1 var_dump object inside object

Tags: php, zend-framework

can somebody please advice how I can var_dump() the Zend_Application object?

```
object(Bootstrap)[3]
public 'frontController' => null
protected '_appNamespace' => boolean false
protected '_resourceLoader' => null
   protected '_application' => 
   object(Zend_Application)[1]
       protected '_autoloader' => 
       object(Zend_Loader_Autoloader)[2]
           protected '_autoloaders' => 
               array (size=0)
...
```

I can var_dump the Bootstrap object with `var_dump($this->bootstrap('view'));` , but I can't figure out how to var_dump the nested Zend_Application object.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is another question why do you want to do that?? It's protected object you can't directly **var_dump** it.

Comment: @Indrasinh Bihola Got it. Thanks. Basically I wanted to understand how to var_dump an object inside an object. I did not know that it is not possible to var_dump protected objects directly. You said you can't var_dump it directly. Is there an "indirect" way to var_dump the Zend_Application object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in Zend Framework 1, you can/should use:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($whatever);
```

Instead of:

```
var_dump($whatever);
```

You can dump application but it will not give you everything. You could change index.php adding:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($application);
```

After :

```
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

The most important thing here is to never forget zf is opensource and you can very much go into the code to look at it, drop Zend_Debug::dump() anywhere you like so you could do what you want. Just revert the zend files back to original after you are done.

Last point: It's possible or even probable that you do not need to dump zend application like that. I do not know what is wrong in your code but its doubtful that its "really" a problem with zend. Reading up on the application object, the bootstrap and zend's mvc in general should help you.

Hope this helps!

Dorian M. added: you can also extend the Zend Object to add the dump in your own function and don't mess up the original code

Comment: you can also extend the Zend Object to add the dump in your own function and don't mess up the original code ;)

Comment: @Iznogood Thanks for your feedback. That helped me to get a better understanding of the Zend bootstrapping process.

Comment: @DorianM Indeed! It can sometimes be pretty complicated tho. Different Zendobjects expect specific objects and your derived classes sometimes just dont cut it. But yeah sure. Very good idea. I'll add your comment to my answer. With credit of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you need `var_dump()` for test codes, i recommend you to use test functions with phpUnit. this is more advantage.